# Airflow run fails but airflow test works. Not sure why

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

So before asking this I've looked through the docs and had a look at [Difference between "airflow run" and "airflow test" in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681325/difference-between-airflow-run-and-airflow-test-in-airflow) to see if I can figure out why I am having this problem.

I've got a few dags, all of which use `LocalExecutor`. Two of them use an `SSHOperator` and the other just runs locally. I've tried `airflow run <some_task_id> <some_execution_date>` and `airflow trigger_dag <dag_id>`, all of which fail. However, when I run `airflow test <task_id> <execution_date>` it works. I should emphasise that this is also the case for the dag that only has a locally ran task.

There seems to be a lot of confusion around the `start_date` in dags, as well as how it relates to `schedule_interval`. All of my dags have a static start_date set to a time in the near past and just for sanity I have the schedule interval `schedule_interval='* * * * *'` so that it runs every minute (it's a lightweight task). When running the dag the task just runs and fails, if retries is set to 0, or it just gets stuck in a retry state if retries > 0, every minute without much feedback at all. All I ever get in task instance details, for each case, is:

`Task instance's dagrun did not exist: Unknown reason.`

or

`Task is not ready for retry yet but will be retried automatically. Current date is 2019-02-20T12:30:35.381668+00:00 and task will be retried at 2019-02-20T12:31:21.492310+00:00.`

There are no logs in the UI despite specifying where they should go in the config file and it telling me where they are from the task instance details page.

Here is an example of one of the dags:

```
import json
import re
from os.path import expanduser
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils import timezone
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
from bw_config_tools.connect.bw_config import ConfigDbClient

CONFIG_DB_INFO = '/etc/airflow/config_db_info.json'
START_SCRIPT = '/bin/start.sh'
TIME_IN_PAST = timezone.convert_to_utc(datetime(2019, 2, 14, 15, 00))

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': TIME_IN_PAST,
    'email': ['example@domain.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

def _extract_instance_id(instance_string):
    return re.findall(r'\d+', instance_string)[0]

def _read_file_as_json(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as open_file:
        return json.load(open_file)

DB_INFO = _read_file_as_json(CONFIG_DB_INFO)
CONFIG_CLIENT = ConfigDbClient(**DB_INFO)

print('Config DB client: {0}'.format(CONFIG_CLIENT))

APP_DIRS = CONFIG_CLIENT.get_values('%solr-mentions-cleanup.[0-9]+.dir%', strictness='similar')

INSTANCE_START_SCRIPT_PATHS = {
    _extract_instance_id(instance_string): directory+START_SCRIPT
    for instance_string, directory in APP_DIRS.items()
    }

# Create an ssh hook which refers to pre-existing connection information
# setup and stored by airflow
SSH_HOOK = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id='solr-mentions-cleanups', key_file='/home/airflow/.ssh/id_rsa')

# Create a DAG object to add tasks to
DAG = DAG('solr-mentions-cleanups',
          default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
          schedule_interval='* * * * *'
          )

DAG.catchup = False

# Create a task for each solr-mentions-cleanup instance.
for instance_id, start_script in INSTANCE_START_SCRIPT_PATHS.items():
    task = SSHOperator(
        task_id='run-solr-mentions-cleanups-{0}'.format(instance_id),
        command='bash {0}  disabled-queries --delete'.format(start_script),
        ssh_hook=SSH_HOOK,
        dag=DAG)
```

and here is the output from running the task:

```
(venv) airflow@some_host ~ # airflow run solr-mentions-cleanups run-solr-mentions-cleanups-0 2019-02-14
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,313] {settings.py:146} DEBUG - Setting up DB connection pool (PID 16375)
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,313] {settings.py:174} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=3600, pid=16375
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,491] {__init__.py:42} DEBUG - Cannot import  due to  doesn't look like a module path
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,645] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,654] {cli_action_loggers.py:40} DEBUG - Adding <function default_action_log at 0x7f0364fdc8c8> to pre execution callback
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,930] {cli_action_loggers.py:64} DEBUG - Calling callbacks: [<function default_action_log at 0x7f0364fdc8c8>]
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,974] {settings.py:146} DEBUG - Setting up DB connection pool (PID 16375)
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,974] {settings.py:154} DEBUG - settings.configure_orm(): Using NullPool
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,976] {models.py:273} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /etc/airflow/dags
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,978] {models.py:360} INFO - File /etc/airflow/dags/__init__.py assumed to contain no DAGs. Skipping.
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,978] {models.py:363} DEBUG - Importing /etc/airflow/dags/hbase-exports.py
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,983] {models.py:501} DEBUG - Loaded DAG <DAG: hbase-daily-export>
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,984] {models.py:363} DEBUG - Importing /etc/airflow/dags/test_dag.py
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,985] {models.py:501} DEBUG - Loaded DAG <DAG: test_dag>
[2019-02-20 12:38:51,986] {models.py:363} DEBUG - Importing /etc/airflow/dags/solr_mentions_cleanup.py
Creating dag
Config DB client: <bw_config_tools.connect.bw_config.ConfigDbClient object at 0x7f032739b4e0>
The key file given is /home/airflow/.ssh/id_rsa
[2019-02-20 12:38:52,196] {base_hook.py:83} INFO - Using connection to: id: solr-mentions-cleanups. Host: some_host, Port: None, Schema: None, Login: some_user, Password: None, extra: {}
extra connection info given:
Key file in extra options:  None
SSH config file being used is  /home/airflow/.ssh/config
[2019-02-20 12:38:52,198] {models.py:501} DEBUG - Loaded DAG <DAG: solr-mentions-cleanups>
[2019-02-20 12:38:52,251] {cli.py:520} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: solr-mentions-cleanups.run-solr-mentions-cleanups-0 2019-02-14T00:00:00+00:00 [success]> on host xxxxxx.net
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,026] {settings.py:146} DEBUG - Setting up DB connection pool (PID 16453)
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,027] {settings.py:174} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=3600, pid=16453
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,207] {__init__.py:42} DEBUG - Cannot import  due to  doesn't look like a module path
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,362] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,371] {cli_action_loggers.py:40} DEBUG - Adding <function default_action_log at 0x7f4345cfa8c8> to pre execution callback
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,622] {cli_action_loggers.py:64} DEBUG - Calling callbacks: [<function default_action_log at 0x7f4345cfa8c8>]
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,658] {settings.py:146} DEBUG - Setting up DB connection pool (PID 16453)
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,658] {settings.py:154} DEBUG - settings.configure_orm(): Using NullPool
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,660] {models.py:273} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /etc/airflow/dags/solr_mentions_cleanup.py
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,662] {models.py:363} DEBUG - Importing /etc/airflow/dags/solr_mentions_cleanup.py

Config DB client: <bw_config_tools.connect.bw_config.ConfigDbClient object at 0x7f4308b5dc50>
The key file given is /home/airflow/.ssh/id_rsa
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,909] {base_hook.py:83} INFO - Using connection to: id: solr-mentions-cleanups. Host: some_host, Port: None, Schema: None, Login: some_user, Password: None, extra: {}
extra connection info given:
Key file in extra options:  None
SSH config file being used is  /home/airflow/.ssh/config
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,912] {models.py:501} DEBUG - Loaded DAG <DAG: solr-mentions-cleanups>
[2019-02-20 12:38:54,961] {cli.py:520} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: solr-mentions-cleanups.run-solr-mentions-cleanups-0 2019-02-14T00:00:00+00:00 [success]> on host xxxx.net
[2019-02-20 12:38:55,054] {cli_action_loggers.py:81} DEBUG - Calling callbacks: []
[2019-02-20 12:38:55,054] {settings.py:201} DEBUG - Disposing DB connection pool (PID 16453)
[2019-02-20 12:38:56,310] {cli_action_loggers.py:81} DEBUG - Calling callbacks: []
[2019-02-20 12:38:56,313] {settings.py:201} DEBUG - Disposing DB connection pool (PID 16375)
```

Furthermore, this used to work until I had to restart everything on the server it was running on, so I'm quite confident that this is close to the version that once worked.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Also, fyi, we have it connected up to a postgres database running on another server. I've confirmed that the state definitely updates which confirms there are no connection issues there.

Comment: any update on this?